# File sharing in Python

Tags: linux, unix, python-3.x, file-sharing

I have 4 computers in a network. I am curios if anyone know how i can i make python to look for some files in different folders from the network or if i can create a mount point that include some folders from different computers. The reason is that i am running a script that needs to open some daemons on different computer. For instance i have the following folders from which i need to run:

```
/temp on 10.18.2.25
/opt on 10.18.2.35
/var-temp on 10.18.4.12
/spam on 10.18.2.17
```

I am using the command `os.system('exec .....')` to launch it , but only works for the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't merely want to execute files stored on different machines on one machine, but on the machines they're stored on. Mounting won't help with that.

You'd need a daemon already running on the target, and tell it over the network to execute a file. [xinetd](http://xinetd.org/) is a common one.